# Collection object returned as undefined using async/await

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I'm setting up an express app to handle SSR for my react app. I need to access Firebase content on one of my routes which is defined as a boolean in my routes.js file.

```
export default [
  {
    component: Home,
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    fetchInitialData: true
  },
  {
    component: About,
    path: '/about',
    fetchInitialData: false
  }
];
```

This is imported through my express app as a normal server sided app to determine whether the route has that boolean set to **true**, which I can then pass the outcome of a function as a prop to my app's components.

```
app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
//Get the matching route object for the URL
  const activeRoute = routes.find((route) => matchPath(url.parse(req.url).pathname, route)) || {}

  let interaction = {}
  const context = {};
  const modules = [];

//If the route object has a fetchInitialData boolean as truthy, set interaction to the result of getDownloadURL
  if(activeRoute.fetchInitialData){
    interaction = await getDownloadURL(req.query.id)
  }

  //THIS IS UNDEFINED, despite using async/await.
  console.log(interaction)

  //Interaction should be set from here. Process rest of app logic
```

I've run into a roadblock with firebase's API, because I cannot include the firebase-admin SDK inside my react app. Therefore I have to run it in the express environment and pass the data down as a prop, hence the reason i'm using a boolean for the required data instead of passing the function directly into the app.
I can't use the normal firebase-sdk because I need to use the storage getDownloadURL function which uses an XMLHttpRequest which isnt compatible with a server, only a browser!

I have defined my own getDownloadURL function inside the express app file which takes a query parameter as a document id and will process the downloadURL for an image stored inside that document.

```
const getDownloadURL = (path) => {
  if(path){
    firestore.collection('interactions').doc(path).get()
      .then(doc => {
        bucket
        .file(doc.data().photoPath)
        .getSignedUrl({
          action: 'read',
          expires: '03-09-2999'
        })
        .then(photoURL => {  
          const interaction = {
            date: doc.data().date,
            venue: doc.data().venue,
            photoURL: photoURL
          }
          //console.log(interaction) <<<<< this returns the valid data.
          return interaction;     
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }else{
    return {};
  }
}
```

This will process the firebase document and eventually end up with a photoURL from the storage API which I am returning as an object to the caller.

I have tried to use Promises instead of async/await by following this structure from this guide: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-server-rendering

```
  const activeRoute = routes.find((route) => matchPath(url.parse(req.url).pathname, route)) || {}

  const promise = activeRoute.fetchInitialData
    ? getDownloadURL(req.query.id)
    : Promise.resolve()

  promise.then((data) => {
  //Rest of app logic, data is still undefined
```

and instead of returning the object from the function, I've just returned the firebase storage promise and handled the promise from the caller.

```
const getDownloadURL = (path) => {
  if(path){
    firestore.collection('interactions').doc(path).get()
      .then(doc => {
        return bucket
          .file(doc.data().photoPath)
          .getSignedUrl({
            action: 'read',
            expires: '03-09-2999'
          })
      }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }else{
    return {};
  }
}
```

However, the result of this function always is undefined and i'm not sure how to fix it at this point. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You never return the promise created by `firebase.collection....` in `getDownloadUrl`.

Comment: How would I go about returning that though if I still need to access the data from that promise, E.G. the photoURL? Could I just handle that data in the caller?

Comment: Just add `return` right before `firestore.collection...`. Make sure it's on the same line. You might also want to modify your else statement to return `Promise.resolve({})` It seems like the rest of your code would work as-is. If it doesn't, you might want to double check if `activeRoute.fetchInitialData` is what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: And if your promise resolves to another promise, then you'll need to call `then` on that promise as well. Try using a debugger, or just console.log the data you get in each then block to see what type of data it is.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help. I made a post about my changes, I got it to work with what you said but maybe my solution is a little clunky? Any way you would go about optimising this perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @KhauriMcClain, I did some code refactoring with what you said and got it to work, I ended up handling the promise from the caller but I was able to get the data I needed to the app which is perfect. One thing to note is that I had to function out my rendering logic because interaction is only defined within the scope of .then and I didnt want to copy and paste my code.

```
app.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  const activeRoute = routes.find((route) => matchPath(url.parse(req.url).pathname, route)) || {}

  let interaction = {}  

  //If the route object has a fetchInitialData boolean as truthy
  // set interaction to the result of getDownloadURL
  if(activeRoute.fetchInitialData && req.query.id){
    interaction = await getDownloadURL(req.query.id)
      .then(doc => {
        bucket
        .file(doc.data().photoPath)
        .getSignedUrl({
          action: 'read',
          expires: '03-09-2999'
        })
        .then(photoURL => { 
          interaction = {
            date: doc.data().date,
            venue: doc.data().venue,
            photoURL: photoURL
          }          
          renderApp(req, res, interaction);
        }).catch(next)
      }).catch(next)
  }else{
    renderApp(req, res, interaction);
  }
})
```

And getDownloadURL is just this now

```
const getDownloadURL = (path) => {
  if(path){
    return firestore.collection('interactions').doc(path).get()
  }else{
    return Promise.resolve({});
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this though? It seems a rather clunky solution since I have to pass req and res to another function to handle my rendering logic.

Answer (score 0):

> Any way you would go about optimising this perhaps?

Mixing `async-await` with `then-catch` isn't great for readability. If you can help it, you might want to refactor further so that your code only uses `async-await`.

I can't guarantee that the following code will work as is, but it should help you get a good idea of what you can do here to refactor your code a little.

1) The code for getting a firestore document isn't too verbose AND you appear to need the document outside of the `getDownloadURL` function so you might consider just moving that to your main function:

```
  if(activeRoute.fetchInitialData && req.query.id){
    const snap = await firestore.collection('interactions').doc(req.query.id).get()
    const data = snap.data()
    // ...
```

2) You can just make `getDownloadURL` an async function and not have to worry about returning promises. Async functions implicitly return promisees. Furthermore, instead of taking the document path, `getDownloadURL` could receive the photoPath, fetch the photoURL, and then return it.

```
const getDownloadURL = async (photoPath) => {
  if(!photoPath){
    return {}
  }
  const photoURL = await bucket.file(photoPath)
    .getSignedUrl({
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-09-2999'
    })
  return photoURL // assuming here that photoURL is an object
}
```

3) Finally, you can replace the rest of the code with some async-await. I also simplified some of the logic here.

```
app.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  const activeRoute = routes.find((route) => matchPath(url.parse(req.url).pathname, route)) || {}

  let interaction = {}  

  //If the route object has a fetchInitialData boolean as truthy
  // set interaction to the result of getDownloadURL
  if(activeRoute.fetchInitialData && req.query.id){
    try {
      const snap = await firestore.collection('interactions').doc(req.query.id).get()
      const data = snap.data()
      const photoURL = await getDownloadURL(data.photoPath)
      interaction = {
        date: data.date,
        venue: data.venue,
        photoURL: photoURL
      }   
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error) // return is important here
    }       
  }
  renderApp(req, res, interaction);
})
```

Your other option here I think would be to rename `getDownloadURL` to `getInteraction` and have it return the full interaction instead of just the URL, but that's up to you.

> It seems a rather clunky solution since I have to pass req and res to another function to handle my rendering logic.

I don't personally see anything wrong with this.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the help. Got it to work by using this in the end and it is much easier to read, so thanks for that.